# Finding a domain that keeps the radius and height of a cylinder positive

Tags: calculus, functions

I am trying to find the domain for the following function:

$$V(r) = r(50-\pi r^2)$$

I realize that normally, the domain would be all real numbers, but in this case the above function represents the volume of a cylinder. So, I want the domain to ensure that the cylinder is physically possible. I know that r (the radius) cannot equal zero, but **what other restrictions are there on the domain?**

Any hints or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make sense for $r$ to be less than zero, so you need it to be positive (not just nonzero).  It also doesn't make sense for the volume to be negative, so the second factor must be positive as well. Does that help?

Comment: That really helps- thank-you! For some reason I didn't clue into the fact that a cylinder with a negative volume wouldn't be very realistic.